# String Array to Tree View - Sort Alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting, treeview

So... I did something I normally don't do, and copy/pasted this function; which does exactly what I need.  I don't have the original source, as it was probably 6 months ago.  The good news is that it works great.  The bad news is that I don't quite understand it and want to make a modification.

This function takes a list of strings that looks like "root\subcat1\subcat2\subcat3," spits it into a string array, and outputs to a hierarchical tree view (displayed in WPF.)

I want to alphabetize the tree on each level.  I see where an empty TreeObject (parent) is added to  iTreeSource... and iTreeSource is being returned, but no modification to it in the loop.  Why not, how is the completed TreeObject added to iTreeSource... and how to alphabetize?  Also, any improvements that can be made would be welcome.

```
private ObservableCollection<TreeObject> TreeLoad(List<string> sortedPath)
{
   ObservableCollection<TreeObject> iTreeSource = new ObservableCollection<TreeObject>();
   TreeObject parent = new TreeObject();
   string pathConstructor = "error";
   iTreeSource.Add(parent);
   foreach (string arrayPath in sortedPath)
   {
      string[] individualPath = arrayPath.Split('\\');
      if (individualPath.Length > 0)
      {
         pathConstructor = individualPath[0];
         parent.Name = individualPath[0];
      }
      parent.Path = pathConstructor;
      TreeObject tempGroup = parent;
      if (individualPath.Length > 1)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < individualPath.Length; i++)
         {
            if (tempGroup.Children.Count != 0)
            {
               foreach (TreeObject matchinGrp in tempGroup.Children)
               {
                  if (matchinGrp.Path == pathConstructor)
                  {
                     tempGroup = matchinGrp;
                     break;
                  }
               }
               if (tempGroup.Path != pathConstructor)
               {
                  TreeObject child = new TreeObject();
                  child.Name = individualPath[i];
                  child.Path = pathConstructor;
                  child.Parent = tempGroup;
                  tempGroup.Children.Add(child);
                  tempGroup = child;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               if (tempGroup.Path != pathConstructor)
               {
                  TreeObject child = new TreeObject();
                  child.Name = individualPath[i];
                  child.Path = pathConstructor;
                  child.Parent = tempGroup;
                  tempGroup.Children.Add(child);
                  tempGroup = child;
               }
            }
            if (i != individualPath.Length - 1 && individualPath.Length > 1)
            {
               pathConstructor = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathConstructor, individualPath[i + 1]);
            }
         }
      }
   }
return iTreeSource;
}
```

Comment: tempGroup is being set to the parent.  Nodes are being added to tempGroup, then tempGroup is moving down the branch.  Its pulled back up to the parent on each new sorted path.  My advice is to go through the tree recursively after its built and sort each Children collection.

Comment: How is it being pulled back up to parent?  parent is added to iTreeSource before the foreach loop (before the TreeObject is filled.)

Comment: after you add all elements why not just call the sort method of the treeview?...which will sort it alphabetically

Comment: There is one parent: TreeObject parent = new TreeObject();  Each sortedPath is reset to it: TreeObject tempGroup = parent; @Sorceri: I thought the same thing, but this seems to be custom Tree not a TreeView.  TreeView would have Nodes not Childern.

Comment: One thing to note, if the number of nodes in the tree is large, is that adding single elements to an Observable collection will fire an update event to the UI control.You might consider a pattern, where the nodes are being inserted at the end in one batch, while events are not triggering. But only consider this if performance is an issue.

Comment: Probably help if he added the class code then.